# Why would the content area for a page say

Tags: template

I inherited an account from someone. I went to make changes to a pages content and in the Content Area it is blank and simply says "in PhP file". And the page editor no longer works. What did the developer do to override the normal editor? Can I fix it back?

Comment: Thank you. I think this developer did something to the core because a lot of functionality is gone. Its a pretty straight forward site. We recently took this over for a client for marketing purposes. The develop has flaked out and we cant get them to respond or follow through on anything. So we are looking for a developer to 1) make a few changes to our product page look but 2) tell is if we need to make some big changes to get Magento to normal so we can add pages ourself. None of it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a `die()` function somewhere left in a Php file. Most likely the developer used it to check if a file has been loaded. If you have shell access, simply do a `grep` of the `app/code` directory for the error message. If you don't have shell access, inspect the files in `app/code/local` and `app/code/community` manually for this message. If you don't find it there, it will most likely be in `app/code/core/Mage/Cms`, but in this case the developer has probably done more modifications to core code, and you should consider a new installation.